# Air Pagination Issues

Tags: air

I just completed an Adobe AIR app. I built it using html, css, javascript and jQuery. It installs fine, loads fine and everything works except pagination on a popup page.

You can install it here: http://www.bendelcorp.com/tools/air-installer.html

When you click on the Capacity tab and enter values in each of the three fields (enter double or triple digits to activate the pagination) and then click on the Show Capacity Chart it brings up another window with data.

The problem - when you click on the Next Page button, nothing happens. The web based version (located [here](http://www.bendelcorp.com/toolscalculators.html)) works fine. I just need some help "unlocking" the power of the Next Page button.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I am the only one reading my entries about Adobe Air.

The fix was in the JavaScript:

```
CapacityWindow = window.open(document.location, 'CapacityWindow', 'toolbar,scrollbars,menubar,width=800,height=950');
```

CapacityWindow.document.write(s);
  CapacityWindow.document.close();

The previous script was not allowing the existing window to close so the new one could open up.